# PHP Mysql PDO code efficiency - Foreach loop within a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo, foreach

**Hello to all!**
I am new to coding and will be studding in class in next September. Looking forward to that....:-)

I am making a modification page for my data base. It's composed of inputs and a drop down list to modify the content of the DB. At least for now...till I learn more.

I am coding for my self and was wondering if the following was the correct way to do this? In my mind it's not, because the inner query gets executed every time the outer loop goes through...But it work!?!?

It's the only way I could find to make the inner FOREACH loop (***$familylist***) work with the Mysql query. If the query for the inner loop is outside the outer loop (***$plantList***)...it does not work. The first drop down list gets populated with the content but the following rows do not, at least only with the first option, it does not get populated with the content from the query.

Any help is welcome and appreciated!

```
<?php //more code here....

$plantQuery = "SELECT id, genre, espece, famille FROM plante ORDER BY genre";

$plantList = $dbconnect->query ($plantQuery);
?>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>GENRE</th>
    <th>ESPÈCE</th>
    <th>FAMILLE</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($plantList->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $plant) : ?>
      <form method="post">
        <tr>
          <td><input name="id" value="<?php echo $plant["id"] ;?>" readonly></td>
          <td><input name="genre" value="<?php echo $plant["genre"] ;?>"></td>
          <td><input name="espece" value="<?php echo $plant["espece"] ;?>"></td>
          <td><select name="familleList" >
              <option value="0" >Choisir une famille</option>
              <?php
                $familyQuery = "SELECT id, famille FROM famille ORDER BY id ASC";
                $familyList = $dbconnect->query ($familyQuery);
              ?>
               <?php foreach ($familyList->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $family):?>
              <option value="<?php echo $family["id"] ;?>" <?php if  ($plant["famille"] <> 0 && $plant["famille"] == $family["id"] ) {echo    "selected"; }?>><?php echo $family["id"] . " - " . $family["famille"] ;?></option>
              <?php endforeach ;?>
            </select>    
         </td> 
         <td><button name="modifier" type="submit">Modifier</button></td>
         <td><button name="supprimer" type="submit">Supprimer</button></td>
       </tr>
     </form>
   <?php endforeach ;?>
 </tbody>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the database multiple times, for the same data inside the `loop`. A simple solution would be to call it once. At the top of the file do something like this.

```
$families = $familyList->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And then you can chance your `foreach` loop to.

```
foreach ($families as $family)
```

This will make the query execute once, and therefor avoid multiple queries to the `database`. And `loop` over the already fetched data in the `loops`.

Comment: Obviously I did not remember the basics! I need to unplug and unwind off code.. Merci!

Answer (score 0):

You were right. What you are doing is very inefficient. Database queries tend to be something that really create a bottleneck, so minimizing them is generally the best thing to do.

Since you are not passing any values into the second query, just take it out of the loop:

```
<?php //more code here....

$plantQuery = "SELECT id, genre, espece, famille FROM plante ORDER BY genre";
$plantList = $dbconnect->query ($plantQuery);

$familyQuery = "SELECT id, famille FROM famille ORDER BY id ASC";
$familyList = $dbconnect->query ($familyQuery);
?>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>GENRE</th>
    <th>ESPÈCE</th>
    <th>FAMILLE</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($plantList->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $plant) : ?>
    <form method="post">
        <tr>
        <td><input name="id" value="<?php echo $plant["id"] ;?>" readonly></td>
        <td><input name="genre" value="<?php echo $plant["genre"] ;?>"></td>
        <td><input name="espece" value="<?php echo $plant["espece"] ;?>"></td>
        <td><select name="familleList" >
            <option value="0" >Choisir une famille</option>
            <?php

            ?>
            <?php foreach ($familyList as $family):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $family["id"] ;?>" <?php if  ($plant["famille"] <> 0 && $plant["famille"] == $family["id"] ) {echo    "selected"; }?>><?php echo $family["id"] . " - " . $family["famille"] ;?></option>
            <?php endforeach ;?>
            </select>    
        </td> 
        <td><button name="modifier" type="submit">Modifier</button></td>
        <td><button name="supprimer" type="submit">Supprimer</button></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
<?php endforeach ;?>
</tbody>   
</table>
```

Even though this is not the case here, whenever you are executing the same query multiple times only changing the variables, you can use prepared statements:

```
$familyQuery = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM famille 
    WHERE something = :s
    AND somethingelse = :se ORDER BY id ASC");
foreach ($values as $val) {
    $familyQuery->bindValue('s', $val);
    $familyQuery->bindValue('se', somefunction($val));
    $familyQuery->execute();
    $results = $familyQuery->fetchAll();
    // Do something with the results
}
```

This way the query is first sent to the DB server and the values are all sent separately.